# Django login AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have this code:

```
 from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
 ...
   if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        existing_user = User.objects.get(email=email)

        user = authenticate(username=existing_user.username, password=existing_user.password)

        login(request, user)
```

According to the docs, this should work, but it doesn't, it gives me the error:

> request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
>   AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Maybe the problem happens becouse I am using JWT Authentication with Django Rest Framework? It is just an django-powered API, so I guess it is a different scenario, but I don't understand what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Show the full traceback. But your code **makes no sense**; `authenticate` is what gets the user, by comparing with the *hashed* password saved in the database. There is no point in getting the user separately, and here `authenticate` will *always* fail.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman . Then how can I login the user in the view without having its password at hand?. The app sends me a facebook token, I confirm the token with Fb's API, then, I get the email and check if it already exists (the rest is in the code I pasted), if the a user with that email exists, I need to login that user. I thought that using `authenticate` and `login` would solve it but now I see it doesn't.

Comment: You can implement your own Authentication Backend to authenticate user without password. There is an example with token authentication here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend .

Comment: Or, use one of the third-party libraries that integrate Facebook login with Django: django-allauth or python-social-auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DRF user should be authenticated inside Authentication class. [This](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) library provides one for JWT auth. It provides both token generation and verification.

You will get user as `self.request.user` in your View or ViewSet class. You just need to allow JWT auth:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication)
```

Or better set is as `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` as documented [here](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage).